# Jqueryui Datepicker scrolls down to the input every-time you click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using [jqueryui Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) - it works fine on desktops but when I tested the datepicker on my iPhone, everytime I click on the previous and next arrows - it scrolls down to the input.

Why does it keep scrolling down to the input every time a click is dedicated on the datepciker widget? What can be done to prevent this?

I have put together a quick test site here: http://loai.directory/test/

Comment: Posting your code here would be helpful and get you more answers.

Comment: You can see the code live on the site @NotoriousPet0

Comment: Sorry, I just thought it would be a good to have a live version to play with as to be honest I don't know what code I could of pasted on here... The whole UI library I am using?